# How can I do this with my image?

Tags: effect, image-manipulation

I saw this series of images:

[image: original photo] [image: reduced to 2 colors] [image: edges only] [image: final image]

<sup>(Click on an image thumbnail to see it larger)</sup>

So I want to get the same from my image:

[image: my original]

I got as far as reducing the colors to 2 (binary):

[image]

But I'm having trouble with the next steps.

Comment: If I understand what your asking, it looks like you need to use an edge detection feature for baby sample #3. You would then blend the inversion of that, along with baby sample #2, with baby sample #1 to achieve baby sample #4.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. @jrista  seems like you understand right I will try to follow your advices.

Comment: @mattdm I'm sorry for stupidness of my question I have bad English. And actually I need to get man_with_the_box looks like baby on 3rd and 4th pics. Thanx

Comment: It's not a matter of the question being stupid. It's a matter of _we don't understand what you're asking_. Can you edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Ok, I want to get all analogs from baby's photo with my man photo. From 3rd baby and 4th baby. I put 1st and 2sd baby's photos as a source pics.

Comment: Is this _your_ man photo, or is it _Getty Images'_ man photo?

Comment: @mattdm Does it matter? As you can see it's not my Image it's ImageGetty's image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the sample set of images with the baby and the cat, here is what I believe has been done:

1. **The original photo was 2-bit posterized, with a low contrast highlight color and black for the darks.**

   - This should be done by duplicating the original photo to a new layer and posterizing the new layer.
   - The levels tool can be used to bring the white point down into gray.
2. **The original photo was run through an edge detection filter.**

   - This should be done by duplicating the original photo to a new layer and edge-detecting the new layer.
   - Invert the edge detected layer if it is dark with light lines, so it ends up with light with dark lines.
3. **Blend the posterized layer with the original photo layer.**

   - You can probably use one of a variety of blending options...use whichever produces the effect you want
4. **Blend the edge layer with the composite of step #3**

   - You could use a "Darker" blend, which would allow all pixels below the edge layer to show through unless the edges are darker than the lower layers
   - You might also try using a screen or overlay filter and some contrast tuning to make the edges show up in a different way

Answer (score 3):

Filters of any editing software will have similar effects. There is also a lot of websites that can do that. A free app for windows that I always recommend is [Paint.net](http://paint.net/), give its filters a try.

Fir this particular effect you just need to use one filter only, on the menu Effects, select container Artistic and then Ink Sketch, Play with the sliders to get the desired effect. You can change the amount of color and the thickness of the line to achieve this effet:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant Pain_t_.net. I'm also pretty sure it doesn't have a filter that will do exactly what the OP wants, at least not without a whole bunch of intermediary steps, and it's those intermediary steps that the OP is asking about.

Comment: No Paint.net is the name of the software, not Pain_t_.net, link provided.

Comment: (The underscore is a way to add emphasis in contexts where bold and italic are not available. In comments, you can't bold a single letter in the middle of a word.)